# JavaScript DataTables - pageLength is not working when applying scroller plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, scroller

When setting `pageLength` property in `DataTables`, the data is divided into multiple pages.
However, when `DataTables.scroller` plugin is applied, the `pageLength` setting is ignored and all data is displayed on one page.

How can I enable the `pageLength` setting while applying the `scroller` plugin?

[Version info]
DataTables: 1.13.1
Scroller: 2.0.7

Comment: Can you share some code here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible to combine **pagination** and **scroller** :

by adding this options :

```
scrollY: '200px', // to enable vertical scrolling. 
paging: true, // is to enable or disable table pagination. (default true)
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        lengthMenu: [
            [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
            [5, 10, 25, 50, 'All'],
        ],
        pageLength: 10,
        scrollY: '200px',
        paging: true
    } );
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.7/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>


<body>
<table id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>Y</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>13</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>316.5454</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>316.5454</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>316.5454</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>316.5454</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>316.5454</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>316.5454</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It helped me to find what happened to my system. Since I already posted the description of the investigation and the cause of the problem, please refer to the post if interested. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As answered above, **pagination** and **scroller** can be combined without any complex settings.

After some investigation, I found what was happening to my environment.
In my system, **DataTable** has to hide the `lengthChange` select box.
Until the **scroller** plugin was applied, the `pageLength` setting had been reflected in the **DataTable** as expected.

However, when I applied **scroller**, the **DataTable** became to show all records instead of the count set as `pageLength` value.
I didn't realize the `pageLength` settings were reset because the `lengthChange` select box is hidden.
(For the investigation purpose, I created the simplified DataTable, but I could not find the 'trap' of the **scroller** specification, then I still suspected *it* was the restriction of the plugin.)

Now I understand the `pageLength` setting will be just ignored when `scroller` is `true`.
If `pageLength` and `scroller` is used together, the `pageLength` value is just needed to set programmatically.
That's simple.

[FYI] Simplified code is shown below:
The behavior can be checked by switching the `scroller` setting to **true** or **false**.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.7/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(() => {
                $('table').DataTable({
                    columns: [
                        { data: 'id' },
                        { data: 'name' }
                    ],
                    pageLength: 5,

                    // This option was the cause of the problem.
                    lengthChange: false,

                    // If 'scroller' option is set as 'true', the 'pageLength' setting is ignored.
                    scroller: true
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th>id</th><th>name</th></tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr><td>1</td><td>Airi Satou</td></tr>
                <tr><td>2</td><td>Angelica Ramos</td></tr>
                <tr><td>3</td><td>Ashton Cox</td></tr>
                <tr><td>4</td><td>Bradley Greer</td></tr>
                <tr><td>5</td><td>Brenden Wagner</td></tr>
                <tr><td>6</td><td>Brielle Williamson</td></tr>
                <tr><td>7</td><td>Bruno Nash</td></tr>
                <tr><td>8</td><td>Caesar Vance</td></tr>
                <tr><td>9</td><td>Cara Stevens</td></tr>
                <tr><td>10</td><td>Cedric Kelly</td></tr>
                <tr><td>11</td><td>Charde Marshall</td></tr>
                <tr><td>12</td><td>Colleen Hurst</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```